# javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject

Tags: java, json, maven, intellij-idea, war

I have a simple Java class in IntelliJ which is given as below:

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {
     @GET
     @Path("/{param}")
     public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
          String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;
          return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
   }
@POST
@Path("/jsonRequest")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getJson(String url) throws InterruptedException, IOException 
{
    JSONObject json= JSONInteraction.readJsonFromUrl(url);
    Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(json);
    return response.build();
}
}
```

I have also included a maven dependency for json as :

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20180130</version>
 </dependency>
```

My war file deployment looks like the following:

[image]

After I start my server and deploy the project, even though all the dependencies are added I still get javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject when I try to run the POST request on POSTMAN. I get correct results when I execute the GET request since it has nothing to do with JSON.

I have read almost all the StackOverflow solutions but none helped. Could someone please help me regarding this issue? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do:

- check if you have added json library inside WAR - unpack your WAR and check if inside is json-20180130.jar
- check if yours server Classloader not contain any other jar with org.json.JSONObject class (for Tomcat: {CATALINA_HOME}/lib) - if it does and this is not JAR provided inside installation package of your server, please remove it - it could be in conflict with class loaded from your WAR
- read very carefully server logs created during your application startup: please search any information about problem with duplicated classes in classloader, loading JAR failures, etc.

If nothing helped, please add:

- pom.xml
- whole stacktrace
- name and version of your servlet container